# Как создать новый список из текущего с новым id

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a =['q','w','e','r','t','y']
b = a
b.pop(2)
print(a)
>>>['q', 'w', 'r', 't', 'y']
```

как сделать что бы программа работала только со списком Б?
Я понимаю, почему так происходит: по факту и А и Б ссылаются на элемент с одним ID и работают с ним. А как это обойти?

Comment: только вчера этот вопрос задавали... b= a.copy()

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию `copy` библиотеки `copy` для **поверхностного** копирования.

```
from copy import copy
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = copy(a)
b.pop(1)
print(b)  # 1, 3, 4
print(a)  # 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Если нужно скопировать сложный объект, то тут уже необходимо **полное** копирование, т.е. функция `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import copy
a = [[1,2,3], 1]
b = copy(a)  # Wrong
b[0][1] = 999
print(b)  # [[1, 999, 3], 1]
print(a)  # [[1, 999, 3], 1]
```

```
from copy import deepcopy
a = [[1,2,3], 1]
b = deepcopy(a)  # Correct
b[0][1] = 999
print(b)  # [[1, 999, 3], 1]
print(a)  # [[1, 2, 3], 1]
```

Comment: Для обычной копии библиотека не нужна, есть встроенная в список `a.copy()`

Comment: @CrazyElf, однако, метод `copy` это поверхностное копирование, а я еще добавил про полное.

Comment: Тогда понятно )